# Meteor form event no communication

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm playing around with the meteor tutorial and I notice that I can't get any feedback from a form submit event; the session variable doesn't get set to 12 and I don't get any printing to the console in the browser (I'm using Chrome). However I do get feedback from the hello click button event in the log and changing of the session variable.

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
    // counter starts at 0
    Session.setDefault('counter', 0);
    Session.setDefault('data', 0);

  Template.hello.helpers({
    counter: function () {
      return Session.get('counter');
    }
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function (event) {
      // increment the counter when button is clicked
      console.log("Button Clicked");
      console.log(event.type);
      Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') + 1 );
    }
  });

  Template.form.events({
    'sumbit form': function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("Form submitted");
      console.log(event.type);
      Session.set('data', 12);      
    }
  });


  Template.results.helpers({
    result: function () {
    return Session.get('data');
    }});
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup });
}
```

This is the html.

```
<head>
  <title>simple-todos</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to my First Meteor App</h1>
  {{ >form }}
  {{ >results }}
  {{ >hello }}
</body>
<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
</template>
<template name="form">
     <form >
        <input type="text"  name = "info" placeholder="" /> 
    </form>
</template>
<template name="results">
  <p> {{ result }} </p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this mistype?

```
Template.form.events({
   'submit form': function (event) {
      ...
   }
});
```

Comment: Embarrassingly the mistype was the error in my code, so it answered my question.